# IBM System p5 9133-55A LCD display error code / alert - what does it mean?

Tags: ibm

On the front of my IBM System p5 9133-55A there is an orange exclamation/alert light that is lit, and a green LCD display that shows:

```
01    N   V=F
          T
```

I tried finding something in the [documentation](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/index.jsp?topic=/iphc5/9133_55A_landing.htm), but could not locate anything.

How do I track down what this means?

Answer (score 2):

Connect to HMC or ASMI and see what they say. You will get error description there, which may be comprehensible (e.g. a fan died somewhere) or utterly cryptic ("there's no detailed description for error code XXXXX"). If it's not something that you can resolve (e.g. "No AC detected for PSU 1", resolvable by re-plugging a loose cable), then call support.

Anyhow, there is no error code on the LCD display, so it seems that machine is currently happily running.

Edit:
Decoding of the panel hieroglyphs:

`01` -- Function Code 01. Function description:

1. Display the currently selected initial program load (IPL) type (and logical key mode on some system types).
2. Display the currently selected IPL speed override for the next IPL.

`N` -- System is booted in normal mode.

`V=F` -- Boot speed is set to fast.

`T` -- The firmware is loaded from temporary side.

There's no `HMC=x`, so your system is not connected to HMC, so you'll have to go to ASMI to see why did it turn the alert LED on.

Comment: Ok, I found information on ASMI (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/powersys/v3r1m5/topic/iphby/iphby.pdf)   So I will check it out and update this.

Answer (score 1):

First thing I usually do is to run `errpt` command

Can you post output of:

```
errpt -a
```

If it doesnt help, we may need ASMI log, because its generally more details